# Removing all notifcations in ToastNotificationManager

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10, toast

I have this code

```
    public void RemoveExistingToastNotifications()
    {
        var TNM = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        var notifications = TNM.GetScheduledToastNotifications();

        for (int i = 0; i < notifications.Count; i++)
        {
            TNM.RemoveFromSchedule(notifications[i]);
        }
    }
```

It works well but it is noticable that performance of this method isn't very good. Is there any better (faster) way to remove all of the notifications (for Windows systems 8.1 and greater)?

Comment: use xperf/WPA to trace which code part are slow: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no alternative API to remove all notification at once. I suggest you submitting a [User Voice of Universal Windows Platform](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) to request this new feature.

Comment: I did as you suggested.